# TestFlight send new update notification

Tags: testflight

I uploaded a new version of my app into TestFlight it’s the Version 0.2. My previous version was 0.121.

After the new version 0.2 was accepted, no one got a push notification to update the app.
Everyone has to click on the public link again or open TestFlight.

Is it possible to send a new notification to all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution: Edit the test information and you'll get immediately a push notification.